# How to add hours to an NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate

I have a date converted to double value and saved in database. Now, I want to compare if `currentDate > myDataBaseDate + 8` hours i.e., I want to get 8 hours added to myDataBaseDate. I'm converting date into double values. So how do I get 8 hours later time from my database saved date. How do I compare

```
if (currentDateTime > DateFromdatabaseValue + DateByAdding8HoursInDataBase)
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you can create an NSDate object by adding time in seconds on to another NSDate using:

`- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds`

//  eg. to add 8 hours to current time:

```
NSDate *mydate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval secondsInEightHours = 8 * 60 * 60;
NSDate *dateEightHoursAhead = [mydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInEightHours];
```

Comment: Avoid using this kind of date math if precision is important to you. You can't assume 60 seconds in a minute, nor 60 minutes in an hour. NSCalendar exists to abstract away all those corner cases (leap seconds, for example).

Comment: tnks buddy...best answer i found

Comment: @BenPackard what's your solution in that case?

Comment: @circuitry It's posted below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30152081/225253

Answer (score 19):

Since iOS 8 there is the more convenient `dateByAddingUnit`:

```
//add 8 hours
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitHour, value: 8, toDate: originalDate, options: nil)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thanks for answering and commenting above.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
NSDate *incrementedDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:numberOfSeconds sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add 8 * 3600 to your database value (assuming that your converted double value represents seconds).

Answer (score 0):

NSDate *startdate = datePicker.date;

```
    NSTimeInterval secondsInOneHours = 1 * 60 * 60;

    NSDate *dateOneHoursAhead = [startdate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInOneHours];

    [dateformate setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss"];

    strDate = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateOneHoursAhead];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.X** Simple usage

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrent
let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: Date())
```