# How to increment one second by a NSDate object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a NSString which have the format of @"2013-01-09 06:10:10 +0000" (I am getting it from server and it is not the current time). I want to increment it by one second continuously. I can use a timer for doing it, but how to increment the time by one second?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSDate *correctDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:1.0 sinceDate:yourDate];
```

You can get yourDate from string using `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays (2017) Apple recommends to use `(NS)Calendar` for all kinds of date math

**Objective-C**

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *nowPlusOneSecond = [currentCalendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitSecond 
                                                       value:1 
                                                      toDate:now 
                                                     options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
```

**Swift 3**

```
let now = Date()
let currentCalendar = Calendar.current
let nowPlusOneSecond = currentCalendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: 1, to: now)!
```

Answer (score 2):

add 1 second in your date like bellow..

```
NSDate *mydate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval secondsInEightHours = 60; // you can add hours and minuts with multiply the numbers with this second..
NSDate *dateEightHoursAhead = [mydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInEightHours];
```

Comment: Downvote for copying code from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1654439/328360) but not fixing it up (not fixing variable names, and the code doesn't actually add one second, it adds 60 seconds)

Comment: @Marko i just post my code which i used before in my apps and i don't know at that time i get solution from which answer so i post my code not copied from any other's answer. i don't know about that but this is code which i posted with my code and logic only.

Answer (score 1):

Say your date string is in var called serverString.  You can get a date this way...

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:serverString];
```

And increment it this way:

```
date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3.x Solution

```
// Just an example to present second level date/time calculation
let time = NSDate()
let interval:Double = 5.0
let timeFiveSecondLater = time.addingTimeInterval(interval)
```